# Make a web UI use tabs on mobile?

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

So I'm making a personal blog, and I'm currently working on a post creation interface. Currently, it's working pretty well (live preview of the post and everything). However, on mobile, the live preview stacks underneath the post. Is there's a way to have the live preview so it's in a separate tab on the web page, but only on a mobile? Code is below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Create Post</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/bootstrap-markdown.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="page-header">
            <h1>New Post</h1>
        </div>

        <form>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="post-title">Post Title</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="post-title" placeholder="">
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <textarea id="editor" name="content" rows="20" placeholder="Start typing here!"></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div id="md-preview" data-provider="markdown-preview"></div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <label class="checkbox">
                <input name="publish" type="checkbox">Publish
            </label>
            <hr/>
            <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
        </form>

    </div>


    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/markdown.js"></script>

    <script src="js/bootstrap-markdown.js"></script>

    <script>
        // A $( document ).ready() block.
        $( document ).ready(function() { console.log( "ready!" ); $("#editor").markdown({autofocus:false,savable:false, height:480}) });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

A live version is avaliable [here](http://rymate.co.uk/editor/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well kinda already figured it out!

Basically I created some tabs that are only visible on smaller devices:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs visible-xs visible-s">
    <li id="editor_tab" class="active">
        <a href="#" id="editor_tab">Editor</a>
    </li>
    <li id="preview_tab">
        <a href="#" id="preview_tab">Preview</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I then used the following monstrocity of javascript to implement the tab behavior:

```
if ($(window).width() < 768) {
    $("#preview").hide()

    $("#editor_tab").click(function () {
        $("#editor_tab").addClass("active");
        $("#preview_tab").removeClass("active");

        $("#textview").show()
        $("#preview").hide()
    });

    $("#preview_tab").click(function () {
        $("#editor_tab").removeClass("active");
        $("#preview_tab").addClass("active");

        $("#textview").hide()
        $("#preview").show()
    });
}
```

Hopefully this helps someone, somewhere in the future.

tl;dr nvm fixed it